# MySQL Tuning for join table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-performance

I have 2 server with almost same specification. let say server A and B. Server A is running some query on daily basis (MySQL 4) and i want to move some of that query and database to Server B. So i setup MySQL 5 on Server B and trying to run identical query, but it takes too slow response time.

```
Server A : MySQL 4, MyISAM, 60s response time 
Server B : MySQL 5, MyISAM, 4222s response time
```

I try to follow Setting Server A to B, but some setting is different cause version different. i copy a whole database with indexes, engine but still so much different in performance.

query something like this

```
select field1, fieldEtc
from table1
left outer join table2 on field1=field2
inner join table3 on field3=field4
inner join table4 on field5=field6 and field15=field16
inner join table5 on field7=field8
inner join table6 on field9=field10
inner join table7 on field11=field12
where field13 >=0

union all

select field1, fieldEtc
from table8
left outer join table2 on field1=field2
inner join table3 on field3=field4
inner join table4 on field5=field6 and field15=field16
inner join table5 on field7=field8
inner join table6 on field9=field10
inner join table7 on field11=field12
where field14 >=0
```

any recommendation which setting i need to change?

UPDATED :

this result show when i add `EXPLAIN` before query

Server A
[image: Server A]

Server B
[image: Server B]

Comment: first thing you can do is prefix your query with `EXPLAIN` and run it.

Comment: @DevZer0 i compare `EXPLAIN` on two servers and got the result. i got some different order and different on field key_len and extra. What does it mean? i need to make them identical?

Comment: can you post explain results to your question, you can edit it

Comment: you should check the `my.cnf` file on both and compare parameters also. like `cache` size etc

Comment: yes i try to follow my.ini on Server A and still looking for the setting, it quite hard because differences of MySQL Version.. yeah i can post explain result on this post but need time to edit it...

Comment: @DevZer0 Hi, i add `explain` result on the post.

Comment: why is your indexes are short on `Server B`

Comment: @DevZer0 it same actually, just different order with Server A

Comment: Did you try to OPTIMIZE the tables after moving it? try OPTIMIZE TABLE table1; OPTIMIZE TABLE table2; OPTIMIZE TABLE table3;  ...

Comment: @Yousf i try `OPTIMIZE` but it didn't work